# Using Streams ... still got Out of Memory

Tags: scala

I am trying to generate a file which contains a very large test data in the form of a json array.

Since my test data is really big I cannot use "mkString". This is also why I am using Streams and tail recursion.

But still my program gets an Out of memory exception

```
package com.abhi

import java.io.FileWriter

import scala.annotation.tailrec

object GenerateTestFile {
  def jsonField(name: String, value : String) : String = {
      s""""$name":"$value""""
  }

  def writeRecords(records : Stream[String], fw : FileWriter) : Unit = {
    @tailrec
    def inner(records: Stream[String]) : Unit = {
      records match {
        case head #:: Stream.Empty => fw.write(head)
        case head #:: tail => fw.write(head + ","); inner(tail)
        case Stream.Empty =>
      }
    }
    inner(records)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val fileWriter = new FileWriter("./sample.json", true)
    fileWriter.write("[")
    val lines = (1 to 10000000)
      .toStream
      .map(x => (
        jsonField("id", x.toString),
        jsonField("FieldA", "FieldA" + x),
        jsonField("FieldB", "FieldB" +x),
        jsonField("FieldC", "FieldC" + x),
        jsonField("FieldD", "FieldD" + x),
        jsonField("FieldE", "FieldE" + x)
      ))
      .map (t => t.productIterator.mkString("{",",", "}"))

    writeRecords(lines, fileWriter)
    fileWriter.write("]")
    fileWriter.close()
  }
}
```

Exception

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:125)
    at scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:95)
    at com.abhi.GenerateTestFile$.jsonField(GenerateTestFile.scala:9)
    at com.abhi.GenerateTestFile$$anonfun$1.apply(GenerateTestFile.scala:32)
```

Comment: What are jvm parameters for memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the source of `Stream`:

```
 *  - One must be cautious of memoization; you can very quickly eat up large
 *  amounts of memory if you're not careful.  The reason for this is that the
 *  memoization of the `Stream` creates a structure much like
 *  [[scala.collection.immutable.List]].  So long as something is holding on to
 *  the head, the head holds on to the tail, and so it continues recursively.
 *  If, on the other hand, there is nothing holding on to the head (e.g. we used
 *  `def` to define the `Stream`) then once it is no longer being used directly,
 *  it disappears.
```

So, if you inline `lines` (or write it as a `def`), and rewrite your `writeRecords` function to not hold onto a reference to the initial head, (or write the param as 'call by name' value using an arrow: `records: => Stream[String]`, which does basically the same thing as `def` vs `val`) elements should be garbage collected as the rest of the stream is processed:

```
@tailrec
def writeRecords(records : Stream[String], fw : FileWriter) : Unit = {
  records match {
    case head #:: Stream.Empty => fw.write(head)
    case head #:: tail => fw.write(head + ","); writeRecords(tail, fw)
    case Stream.Empty =>
  }
}


writeRecords((1 to 10000000)
  .toStream
  .map(x => (
    jsonField("id", x.toString),
    jsonField("FieldA", "FieldA" + x),
    jsonField("FieldB", "FieldB" +x),
    jsonField("FieldC", "FieldC" + x),
    jsonField("FieldD", "FieldD" + x),
    jsonField("FieldE", "FieldE" + x)
  ))
  .map (t => t.productIterator.mkString("{",",", "}")), 
fileWriter)
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is not a stream but an iterator that materialises that list of values one by one; also after you process it i.e. save to file throws away the memory.

When you create your json you actually hold in memory the entire sequence of numbers and in addition to that you generate for each element a new large text blog which you later put in the file. Memory wise the initial sequence is insignificant compared to the size of the text.
What I've did is I've used a for comprehension to create an iterator that releases elements one by one. With foldLeft I make sure that i map the element to a json string, write it do disk and release the memory (the reference to any created object is lost therefore GC can kick in an reclaim the memory. unfortunately with this approach you cannot make use of the parallelism features.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fileWriter = new FileWriter("./sample.json", true)
    fileWriter.write("[")

    fileWriter.write(createObject(1).productIterator.mkString("{", ",", "}"))

    val lines = (for (v <- 2 to 10000000) yield v)
                .foldLeft(0)((_, x) => {
                  if (x % 50000 == 0)
                    println(s"We've reached $x element")

                  fileWriter.write(createObject(x).productIterator.mkString(",{", ",", "}"))
                  x
                })

    fileWriter.write("]")
    fileWriter.close()
  }

  def createObject(x: Int) =
    (jsonField("id", x.toString),
      jsonField("FieldA", "FieldA" + x),
      jsonField("FieldB", "FieldB" + x),
      jsonField("FieldC", "FieldC" + x),
      jsonField("FieldD", "FieldD" + x),
      jsonField("FieldE", "FieldE" + x))
```